# Xamarin iOS - Parse.com issue registering subclasses?

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working with Parse.com whilst building an app with Xamarin for iOS. I have built an Android version with no issues, everything working. However, when I try to register a Custom Parse Object before initializing Parse.com client I have an issue where I can't actually register objects.

[image]

As you can see my Parse iOS project is trying to reference the Parse Android library. I have no idea why?

Has anybody else seen this or know if I am registering these classes incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so managed to figure this one out.

As I have a shared code library for both Android and iOS that references the Parse library, I needed to make sure that the shared code library references the Parse version of the platform I was working on.

For example, whilst building my Android application the shared code library that referenced Parse objects needed to reference the Parse.Android library.

When moving to iOS part of the project I made sure my shared code library referenced the Parse.iOS library.

Hope this makes sense to anyone out there.